# iOS Push Segue only performs sometimes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, viewdidload

I've got this really weird bug on my code, and I have no idea on how to solve it.

I'm using the stroryboard scheme as shown on the picture attached. One navigation controller, that performs a push segue programatically, and, when clicking the "Find" button, the "findsegue" is supposed to be performed.

So, the problem is: Randomly, the view is not loaded. viewDidLoad is executed, but nothing changes on my screen. Some other times, it all works like a charm.

Here is the code that is called when the "Find" button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)encontreBtn:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Segue is going on");
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"findsegue" sender:sender];
}
```

@"Segue is going on" is always printed.
And that's the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"DIDLOAD");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  _topBar.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"LibelSuit-Regular" size:23];
  _topBar.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  _tableView.dataSource = self;
  _tableView.delegate = self; 
}
```

@"DIDLOAD" does print as well.
As a note, viewDidAppears runs as well.[image]

Comment: Does `DIDLOAD` print every time?  If `DIDLOAD` prints, the stuff in `viewDidLoad` should have been executed.  With that said, `viewDidLoad` doesn't get called every time the view appears.

Comment: Yup. DIDLOAD does print everytime.
After pressing the "Find" button, the segue is fired, "Segue is Going On" print, as well as "DIDLOAD".

Comment: And what on your screen do you expect to change?  There's nothing in your `viewDidLoad` that would be different from one load of the screen to the next as far as I can tell, nothing really dynamic...

Comment: Well, the next scene. (The Encontre View Controller scene)
The controller that is shown after I click "Find" is the same as "View Controller Home".

Comment: When I click "Find", sometimes the next scene is loaded, sometimes it's not.
 `viewDidLoad` does run, as well as viewDidAppear. But the screen does not change.
If I restart the simulator one or two times, the next scene does appear as it should.

Comment: When you say "sometimes", what does that mean exactly?  Does it load the first time every time?

Comment: It's completely random. If it does work on the first try, it will keep working until I close the simulator.
If it doesn't work, it won't work until I close the simulator.

Comment: When it doesn't work, is `viewDidLoad` being called?

Comment: Yes. viewDidLoad is being called, even if it does not work.

Comment: And the program doesn't crash?  It just doesn't load?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43471/discussion-between-arthur-camara-and-nhgrif)

Comment: Does "findsegue" specifically connect the Find button to the next view controller or does it generally connect the one view controller to the next?

Comment: @Lyndsey, that's general. The segue is connecting the ViewControllers, not the button itself.